# Using expect in Perl, how to add options of ignoring case with method $object->expect()?

Tags: perl, expect.pm

This is example found in perldoc:

```
  $object->expect(15, '-re', "$str");
```

I want to add option 'i' to the match. This won't work:

```
$object->expect(15, '-re', qr/$str/i);
```

Do I have to use this format:

```
 $exp->expect($timeout, [ qr/$str/i, sub {}], $shell_prompt);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can embed directives into the regex itself:

```
$object->expect(15, '-re', "(?i)$str");
```

ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns

Comment: `qr/foo/i` is actually `(?i:foo)`. `(?i)foo` generally equivalent, but it relies on Expect embedding the pattern in `(?:...)` to limit the scope of the case-insensitivity.

Comment: It will rely on $str not containing an unmatched close parenthesis. I suppose we'll have to assume it's a well-formed regex in the first place, or rely on the rest of the code to catch the error.